# ing and ing does ?. Is it correct?

Tags: meaning, present-tense

**The daily freezing and melting of water causes large rocks to break up into smaller pieces.**

I have faced a sentence and can't understand what is meaning of it. As far as I know after noun + and + noun we have to use verb for plural, but the sentence says different. Please help me. 
Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: You might be interested in our [sister site for English learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com)... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the **process** of "**daily** freezing and melting" that requires the singular verb **causes**.

But if you would like to see the plural, perhaps

> The freezing and melting of water cause large rocks to break up into
>   smaller pieces.